Placing a value inside a function
In vue.js, I want to be able to do this:
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in preDefItems">
      <span v-model="itemName">{{ item.name }}, {{ item.price}}</span>
      <input type="button" value="+" v-on:click="addItem({{item.name}}, {{item.price}}, {{item.name}})"/>
  </li>
</ul>

And then use methods addItem() function, to retrieve the value. But what I found is that the above does not work?
I want to access a function with vue.js and send values.

@focus event to set value on input.

You need to use it as below:
<input type="button" value="+" v-on:click="addItem(item.name,item.price)"/>


Does not work... I updated my example with the code.

I could not understand why you are passing props into addItem function when you are not using it into the same
